# 'pursue' and 'pursue out of'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

As I understand a verb 'pursue' has different meanings here. Am I right or maybe there is one meaming for 'persue' and 'pursue' with 'out of'?

> Cromlechs and menhirs, flint implements and neolithic graves, he
>   **pursued** them ruthlessly; and his elder son **pursued** the portable trophies just as ruthlessly **out of** the house when he came
>   into his inheritance.

THE FRENCH LIEUTENANT’S WOMAN
by John Fowles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read the excerpt several times before I understood it, because "pursued ... out of the house" would make no sense on its own.

Fowles is indulging in word-play. It would make almost no sense to say "After his father died, he pursued his father's trophies out of the house". Only after the first "pursue" is it comprehensible - and in that context, suggests the same wild enthusiasm to get rid of them as his father had shown in collecting them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they indeed have different meanings.

> flint implements and neolithic graves, he ***pursued*** them ruthlessly

here it implies he *"continuously investigated or explored"*

while

> ***pursued*** the portable trophies just as ruthlessly ***out of*** the house

is closer to the meaning of his son having *'chased out'* the portable trophies , in the sense that he threw them away, out of the house.

Note that the difference between *pursued* and *pursued out of* is the same as *chased after* and *chased out of*.

When you **chase after** someone, you follow them- in pursuit/ to catch them.

When you **chase out** someone (from somewhere), you want to kick them out of the place. There is a feeling of hostility involved.

Comment: What about: You might think I'm going out of my mind
But I'm chasing out my dream
`Cause I would go to the moon and back
Just to tell you how I feel. Here chasing out is the same as 'chase after'.

Comment: Well.. you might be right. There is no hard and fast rule to this. But I still think, in **general** conversation, 'chasing after dreams' sounds more fitting than 'chasing out dreams'. Song lyrics don't always use correct English.